# XeLaTex error with spaces in name MiKTeX 2.9 update

Tags: spacing, xetex

Since the last MiKTeX 2.9 update, I am unable to compile .tex files with spaces in names, e.g. "file with spaces in name.tex"
Any minimal file, as

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

show the error

```
Process started: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "file with spaces in name".tex
xelatex.exe
: Invalid argument: "file with spaces in name".log xelatex.exe: Data: "file with spaces in name".log
Process exited with error(s)
```

either with TeXstudio or TeXworks.
This is a known problem of the update - https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2352/ - (I have never before had any problem and this happens with files that were working *before* the update.

This is just for a heads-up and in case anyone has any workaround. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is all quite true but doesn't really fit into the Q&A format: it's a bug which only Christian Schenk can fix and which has been logged.

Comment: Since this is a known bug and definitely a software problem on the distribution level there really is not much we can do here. This is more of a Q&A site and not a mailing list.

Comment: The work-around is: rename your files. Or use lualatex.

Comment: Sorry. I just noticed the bug and spent around 3h before I found out the origin of the bug. Hence the need to share: so that others don't lose time finding an answer where there is none to be had. I know that this does not quite fit the Q&A, but as I saw other questions related to bugs, I thought I might give it a try.
Furthermore (and I still have hope), someone might have a workaround which is not "rename your files". I don't want to have to rename them. And I compile in xelateX because of the unicode input flexibility. Never tried lualatex
(Btw: ty for the welcome)