# How to configure TexStudio to compile using XeLatex for Calibri Font?

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdf, luatex, fontspec

I am trying to make the Calibri font work in TexStudio.

Following several posts on here I included the command in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=text-tex]{Calibri}
```

And went into

> Options -> Configure TexStudio -> Build -> Default Compiler ->
>   LuaLatex

Which worked when I compiled, but it too upwards 40 seconds.

So another suggestion is to use XeLatex, so I did the same thing:

> Options -> Configure TexStudio -> Build -> Default Compiler ->
>   XeLatex

[image]

And received error:

[image]

Many users here said that using Xelatex to compile worked instantly, so I don't understand why it isn't working for me. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: @Bernard Oh I see, there was a space in the file name. Something related to XeLatex not being able to process file with spaces in them http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238232/xelatex-error-with-spaces-in-name-miktex-2-9-update Anyways this problem has been resolved ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as its owner marked it as resolved.

Comment: Please post the solution in an answer below, don't edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protip: Don't have file names with empty space in them such as

"Spider Man"

Or

"Dolly Parton"

For whatever reason XeLatex compiler can't handle them.